# How to import the six library to python 2.5.2

Tags: python, python-import

I'm wondering how I can import the six library to python 2.5.2? It's not possible for me to install using pip, as it's a closed system I'm using.

I have tried to add the six.py file into the lib path. and then use "import six". However, it doesnt seem to be picking up the library from this path.

Comment: `six` only supports Python 2.6 and newer.

Comment: Ahh I see, saved me a lot of time, thx v much :)

Answer (score 1):

According to project history, [version 1.9.0](https://bitbucket.org/gutworth/six/src/a9b120c9c49734c1bd7a95e7f371fd3bf308f107?at=1.9.0) supports Python 2.5. Compatibility broke with 1.10.0 release.

> Six supports every Python version since 2.5. It is contained in only
>   one Python file, so it can be easily copied into your project. (The
>   copyright and license notice must be retained.)

[There is a commit in version control system which mentions change of minimum supported version](https://bitbucket.org/gutworth/six/commits/2dfeb4ba983d8d5985b5efae3859417d2a57e487).

Note that pip is able to install fixed version of package if you want to.

```
pip install six==1.9.0
```

Comment: Great thanks for this, any idea how to install modules without pip?

Comment: copy-paste it to working dir or any other dir listed in `sys.path`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `six` on Python 2.5; it requires Python 2.6 or newer.

From the [`six` project homepage](https://bitbucket.org/gutworth/six):

> Six supports every Python version since 2.6.

Trying to install `six` on Python 2.5 anyway fails as the included `setup.py` tries to import the `six` module, which tries to access objects not available in Python 2.5:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):    
  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
  File "/private/tmp/test/build/six/setup.py", line 8, in <module>
    import six
  File "six.py", line 604, in <module>
    viewkeys = operator.methodcaller("viewkeys")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'methodcaller'
```